# How to convert an closed path SVG to a 0-1 array

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, svg

Lets say there is a svg with a closed filled rectangle in the middle and around that there's a white space of 2 points .

```
<path d="M2 2 H 3 V 3 H 2 Z" fill="transparent" stroke="black"/>
```

So I want to represent this a 2-d matrix where all the white space are represented as 0 and black spaces (covered area) is represented as 1. so for this example it should be-

```
 [
   [0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 1]
 ]
```

It's a simple path , but I'm trying to find a way where it would work for complex paths including bezier curve. Actually I'm trying to convert an **SVG world map to 0-1 matrix** so that I can run some AI algorithms on it .

Comment: This is not possible this way. Well it's not "impossible" but... The idea to convert simple paths in 0-1 matrix is not that bad, but bezier curves is simply "weird". How can you / would you define the curve precision you want to keep? for example, a curve defined on a small area, the starting point and the end point may be enough, but if the curve is wide and you want it to keep a good precision, you may need several points to represent it with your matrix...

Comment: lets say each array element represent a <div/> of 1 * 1  px . and if the `svg path passes across that pixel` or `that pixel (/ part of that px) falls under the closed area` then it got the value of `1` other wise `0`

Comment: yeah, got it, but what about precision? a bezier curve could represent an infinity of points... That's the svg, vectorial point! You can size it as wide as you want, you do not really have that "pixel size" limitation with this format...

Comment: Draw the path to canvas and read off the pixel values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented @Robert Longson suggestion. ***1)*** Draw the svg in canvas ***2)*** Get ImageData as CanvasContext Array ***3)*** Iterate on that array and form your matrix. ***4)*** Array returned by `getImageData` is a flat array and `consecutive 4 array index` correspond to one point of canvas and they are r, g, b and alpha (rgba) of the color of that point.

Here's a working react component .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class IndexPage extends Component {

  constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);
    this.canvasWidth = 1052;
    this.canvasHeight = 580;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const mapCanvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      this.arrayFromSvg();
    }.bind(this);
    img.src = 'World.svg';
  }

  render() {
    return ( < div >
     < div styles={{
        width: this.canvasWidth,
        height: this.canvasHeight
      }
      } >
        < canvas width = {
      this.canvasWidth
      }
      height = {
      this.canvasHeight
      }
      ref = "canvas" >
        < /canvas> < /div >
        < /div>
      );
  }

  arrayFromSvg() {
    const mapCanvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const canvasWidth = mapCanvas.width;
    const canvasHeight = mapCanvas.height;
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight).data;
    const imageToMat = [];

    for (let row = 0, count = -1; row < canvasWidth; row++) {
      imageToMat[row] = [];
      // imageToMat[row][col] = 'rgba(' + imageData[++count] + ', ' + imageData[++count] + ', ' + imageData[++count] + ', ' + imageData[++count] + ')';
      for (let col = 0; col < canvasHeight; col++) {
        if (imageData[++count] + imageData[++count] + imageData[++count] + imageData[++count] > 0) {
          imageToMat[row][col] = 1;
        } else {
          imageToMat[row][col] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(imageToMat);
  }
}
```